# How to verify JWT token with ES384 algorithm with Nodejs tools signed with JwtSecurityTokenHandler using CNG keys

Tags: node.js, jwt, cng

I'm trying to verify JWT token with Node.js tools signed with [JwtSecurityTokenHandler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/) using CNG generated keys

I tried many Nood.js tools e.g. [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken)

```
jwt.verify(token, publickey,{ algorithms: ['ES384'], ...
```

But get wrong tag errors every time

```
["error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error"],"library":"asn1 encoding routines","function":"asn1_check_tlen","reason":"wrong tag","code":"ERR_OSSL_ASN1_WRONG_TAG"
```

The public and private keys generated with CNG

```
 var key = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.ECDsaP384, "keyName",
                new CngKeyCreationParameters
                {
                    KeyCreationOptions = CngKeyCreationOptions.OverwriteExistingKey,
                    KeyUsage = CngKeyUsages.AllUsages,
                    ExportPolicy = CngExportPolicies.AllowPlaintextExport,
                });

            txtPrivateKey = Convert.ToBase64String(key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob));
            txtPublicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob));
```

I tried with [converting the keys](https://github.com/sdcb/Ecd2Pem), but still getting the same exception.
How can I generate a valid public key for Node.js tools using CNG and ES384 algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found the solution:

1. export private key in pkcs8 format

`Convert.ToBase64String(key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob));`

2. save into pem and add BEGIN/END PRIVATE KEY
3. generate public key with openssl

`openssl ec -in pkcs8.pem -pubout -out pkcs8genpubkey.pem`